# How the OS X generate the icon phash?

Tags: macos, airdrop, phash

I have tried to use wireshark to sniff airdrop function in OS X, I found that there is a element call phash.

```
TXT: phash=upHAXlRUnb0ICgY2uDUpw6cv5fI=
```

When  using the AirDrop, the appearance icon will be your user icon if you have set it. I have tried to change the icon a lot of time , open the airdrop and using wireshark to capture the phash value, because the phash value is generated by OS X itself, it is correct, so I can use scapy to change the phash value which from my record and resend it, it will appear the icon on the AirDrop. I think the OS X have its method to generate the value, I want to know it so that I don't need to repeat to change icon and capture it.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is on topic here, and if this is, we'll need a lot more information about that

Comment: I think it could be [this library](http://www.phash.org/docs/) as it talks about image hashes in the documentation.

Comment: @Thomas When you using the AirDrop, the appearance icon will be your user icon if you have set it. I have tried to change the icon a lot of time , open the airdrop and using wireshark to capture the phash value, because the phash value is generated by OS X itself, it is correct, so I can use scapy to change the phash value which from my record and resend it, it will appear the icon on the AirDrop. I think the OS X have its method to generate the value, I want to know it so that I don't need to repeat to change icon and capture it.

Comment: @Droppy Thank you, I have seen this before, and I think it is used to compare two pictures, but can not generate the above phase value.

Comment: You should [edit] your question when you add information :)